# how to write sql query to find the first and last name of users from the youngest and oldest age of each gender?

Tags: sql

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7mP3.png)

I have dataset looks like in the picture, where do I start to get query like i wrote on the title.

thanks

Comment: what have tried? where did you get stuck?

Comment: I dont know where to start. Dont get it how to select just one name for youngest or oldest grouped by gender

Comment: look up Min(),/Max(), aggregate functions  and HAVING clause or Lateral joins.  You need to fish a bit yourself before we just provide you an answer.  Reading, researching is part of the learning needed.

Comment: Thank you, im already tried, but no clue at all.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to post the output format and sample data-set in question.

Following is something that you can use to get min and max ages across gender -

```
with agg_cte as
(select first_name, last_name, gender,age,
max(age) over (partition by gender) max_age,
min(age) over (partition by gender) min_age
from users)
select first_name,last_name,age,gender,
case when age=max_age and gender='F' then 'female_with_max_age' 
when age=min_age and gender='F' then 'female_with_min_age' 
when age=max_age and gender='M' then 'male_with_max_age' 
when age=min_age and gender='M' then 'male_with_min_age' end as classification
from agg_cte 
where age=max_age
or age=min_age
```

Refer to fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rv29G4KHiYXpEcvgeEgqsu/0).